# replacing blank not NA

Tags: r

I have two variables `a` and `b`

```
a         b
vessel    hot
parts     
nest      NA
best      true
neat      smooth
```

I want to replace blank in `b` with `a`

```
la$b[i1] <- ifelse(la$b[i1] == "",la$a[i1],la$b[i1])
```

But it is not working

Comment: What is `i1`? It looks like it should just be 2...

Comment: I have more than 1000 records like this. So i cant specify 2  i mentioned i1 to go through all records

Comment: Oh, then just get rid of all the brackets: `la$b <- ifelse(la$b == "",la$a, la$b)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), specify the condition in 'i' (`b==''`), and assign the values of 'a' that corresponds to TRUE values in 'i' to 'b'.  It should be fast as we are assigning in place.

```
library(data.able)
setDT(df1)[b=='', b:= a]
df1
#       a      b
#1: vessel    hot
#2:  parts  parts
#3:   nest     NA
#4:   best   true
#5:   neat smooth
```

---

Or we can just `base R`

```
i1 <- df1$b=='' & !is.na(df1$b)
df1$b[i1] <- df1$a[i1]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = c("vessel", "parts", "nest", "best", "neat"
), b = c("hot", "", NA, "true", "smooth")), .Names = c("a", "b"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
# la$b[i1] <- ifelse(la$b[i1] == "",la$a[i1],la$b[i1])
# what is i1? it doesn't seem to have any obvious function here
```

... it should be:

```
la$b <- ifelse(la$b == "", la$a, la$b)
```

assuming that you want to replace blank in b with a and that applies to all blanks

### it works:

```
df <- structure(list(a = c("vessel", "parts", "nest", "best", "neat"
), b = c("hot", "parts", NA, "true", "smooth")), .Names = c("a", 
"b"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

df$b <- ifelse(df$b=="", df$a, df$b)
# or, with `with`: df$b <- with(df, ifelse(b=="",a,b))
#  > df
#       a      b
# 1 vessel    hot
# 2  parts  parts
# 3   nest   <NA>
# 4   best   true
# 5   neat smooth
```